# Creating a styled VCL component

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I am trying to create a custom VCL component in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin that is derived from `TGraphicControl` and kind of looks like a `TProgressBar`.

I want it to draw itself using the *Windows Theme* system.  In order to do this, I have included `Vcl.Themes.hpp` in my source code, and overwritten the virtual `Paint()` method to call the `TCustomStyleServices::DrawElement` method.

The problem is the **64 bit** linker complains that `Vcl::Themes::TCustomStyleServices::DrawElement` cannot be resolved.

How do I satisfy the linker?

Comment: That exact problem was supposedly [fixed in 10.1 Berlin](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44675).  Specifically, see [RSP-12237 "Vcl::Themes::TCustomStyleServices::DrawElement unresolved externals"](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12237) and [RSP-12297 "ilink64 Errors with VCL Themes"](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12297). Maybe your package is missing a reference to the package that implements `TCustomStyleServices`?